# How to get currently active item`s index number (and not active item`s id) on a card layout on Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How do I get the currently active item's index number (and not active item's id) on a card layout?
The following code will return active item's id:

```
     Ext.getCmp('my-wizard').getLayout().activeItem.id];
```

What if I don't want to define an id for my component items and I just want to access active item's index number?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I couldn't find a built-in quick and easy way, but the following would work:

```
var wiz = Ext.getCmp('my-wizard');
var activeItem = wiz.getLayout().activeItem;
var activeIndex = wiz.items.indexOf(activeItem);
```

If this was something that you wanted to do often, you could add it to the `CardLayout` prototype:

```
Ext.override(Ext.layout.CardLayout, {
    getActiveIndex: function() {
        return this.container.items.indexOf(this.activeItem);
    }
});
```

Then you could use it with:

```
var activeIndex = Ext.getCmp('my-wizard').getLayout().getActiveIndex();
```

Comment: Quick note:  I didn't notice your question was tagged with `extjs4`, and my answer applies to ExtJS 3, so it may or may not work with ExtJS 4.

Comment: Thanks for your very practical and working answer.sorry that stackoverflow doesn`t let me vote up...